# Regex do not allow more than one at symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I am going to validate an e-mail address in a specific way. I want to make sure the e-mail has only one @ symbol and no more.

I can't figure out what the regex should look like. I can't find any good examples of how you would match more than one of a specific character in a string, but let the first occurrence of it pass.

I want to say something like:

```
/@.@/ or /@*@/ or /*@*@*/
```

So far, nothing is working.

The expression should match:

```
me@me@me.com
me@me@me@me.com
me@@me.com
```

It should not match:

```
me@me.com
```

Comment: The title suggests you want a pattern to match strings with exactly one `@`, but the body says you want a pattern to match strings with more than one `@`. Please update the question to be more clear on exactly what you want.

Comment: my *guess* is that he means individual emails in the string and just didn't format his list of examples properly.  But agreed, OP should clarify.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert, but it's my understanding that regexes should generally be designed to match pass cases and not fail cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two or more @ symbols: `@[^@]*@`.

Edit: The regex can be thought of in three steps:

- `@`: require an @ symbol (note that it doesn't have the `^` so the @ symbol can be anywhere in the string
- `[^@]*`: any non-@ character, or none
- `@`: if any other @ symbol is found then it is a match

I hope that this explains the regex at least a little bit.

Comment: Simply giving the regex expression does not make a good answer. Please explain what the expression does so that the OP can learn.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. the [^@] was beyond me. Good job. It says [^@]* any non-@ character, but it matches me@@me.com. So i'll have to figure that one out later. :)

Comment: I've edited the explanation, the `[^@]*` may or may not match another character, because of the `*` following the test `[^@]`: [link that explains the *](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 5):

alternative to regex:

```
var email = "foo@bar.com";
if (email.split('@').length==2) {
  // only has 1 '@'
}
```

Comment: This is how I'd rather do it - regex is too slow to use for something this simple

Comment: `// has one and only one` That's my correctness policing of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Why not match emails that contain *only one* @:

```
^[^@]*?@[^@]*?$
```

Comment: Without proper clarity on the question this answer hangs in a 50% correct balance. Also, please see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255405/improving-regexp-answers) to improve regex answers.